# How to assign copy of object back to original reference?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have application with following design:
Table View that lists documents.
And ViewController where document is edited.

When editing the document I want to use a copy of object so in case user press Cancel I just throw away the copy. If user selected Save I copy modified document to original.
(I can't have all document's fields as properties in viewController because there are too many of them).

Table View controller:

```
SelectedRowAtIndex {
  document= [documentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  viewController.assignedDocuemnt= document;
}
```

Then I have View controller class where the item is modified:

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic,retain) Document *asignedDocument;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Document *editedDocument;

viewDidLoad{
   editedDocument= [assignedDocuemnt copy];
}


IBAction save {
   assignedDocument=editedDocument;
}
```

**My problem is that original document in documentsArray is not updated with edited version.
What did I miss?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying the value and then assigning the reference of the copy back over *a reference* to the original. That's definitely not going to work.

First, keep track of which document they're adding in the table view's viewcontroller.

Then add a handler for replacing the selected document with another to the table view's viewcontroller:

```
- (void)replaceSelectedDocument:(Document*)newDoc {
    [documents replaceObjectAtIndex: editingIndex
                         withObject: newDoc];
}
```

To save, call the table view controller's new message from the editor view controller with something like:

```
[tableViewController replaceSelectedDocument: editedDocument];
```

A better way to do this would be to modify your editor view controller to take a target and action instead of calling back to the table view controller explicitly. When you want to save, call the action:

```
[target performSelector: action withObject: editedDocument];
```

But that's another bump on the learning curve that you probably don't need to get over today.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Could you elaborate about last part, the "better way" ? I'm holding the documents array in separate Data class as singleton.

Comment: I just meant better compared to hard-coding which message to send to the table view controller. If you send `replaceSelectedDocument`, you've forever coupled those objects. If you instead pass `target: self action: @selector(replaceSelectedDocument:)`, you've kept it flexible and uncoupled: The editor doesn't actually care that it was called by the table view controller, it just knows it should send a message specified to it to a target specified to it when it's done.